# Use of Select() cpp with tracking client data needs

Tags: c++, sockets, select, winsock2

First off I am still very new to c++. I am trying to write a GNSS internet radio caster program. Basically when a client logs in and is accepted my program stores what data stream source the client requests in a Client class. I was going to match an array of Client objects and an array of clientSockets using the index number of both arrays however trying to use Select() to check nonblocking sockets has made that complicated. I have found some examples of implementing Select() but I'm not certain how to track the original clientSocket from my array that I use to accept the connection from the listenSocket with.

```
    class Client{
            public:
            std::string  source;
            std::string  user;   //stored in txt file as name:password
            boolean      connected;
            int          IndexNumber;

    };
typedef struct _MYSOCKET_INFORMATION{
  char Buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
  WSABUF DataBuf;
  SOCKET Socket;
  DWORD SendBytes;
  DWORD RecvBytes;
}SOCKET_INFORMATION, *LPSOCKET_INFORMATION;
// creates number of objects of this structure
LPSOCKET_INFORMATION SocketList[NUMBER_CLIENTS];

FD_SET Writer;
FD_SET Reader;
DWORD TotalSockets = 0;
DWORD Flags;
u_long NonBlock = 1;
timeval tv;
long tv_sec = 1;
long tv_usec = 0;
//intiate objects
Caster caster;
DataStream datastream[NUMBER_BASES]; //100 base stations max
Client client[NUMBER_CLIENTS];
SOCKET listenSocket;
SOCKET clientSocket[NUMBER_CLIENTS];
SOCKET serverSocket;
char recvArray[BUFFERSIZE];
using namespace std;
int main()
{
//initialize the Read and Write socket sets
    FD_ZERO(&Reader);
    FD_ZERO(&Writer);
    //check for connection attempt
    FD_SET(listenSocket, &Reader);
    FD_SET(serverSocket, &Reader);
    //set read and write state based on state of buffer

    for( unsigned int i=0; i<TotalSockets; i++){
        if( SocketList[i]->RecvBytes < SocketList[i]->SendBytes){
            FD_SET(SocketList[i]->Socket,&Writer);
        }
        else{
            FD_SET(SocketList[i]->Socket,&Reader);
        }
    }

    //Select returns number of sockets ready to be read/writen
    Total = select(0, &Reader, &Writer, NULL, &tv);
    if(Total == SOCKET_ERROR){
        printf("Error select function %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
if( FD_ISSET(listenSocket, &Reader)){
        Total--;
        //set current client no
        while(client[current].connected == true){
            current++;
            if(current >= NUMBER_CLIENTS){
                current = 0;
                count++;
                if(count >= 2){//has cylcled twice all must be set to true, can add no more.
                    count =0;
                    printf("client limit reached.\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        clientSocket[current] = accept(listenSocket, NULL, NULL); //setup client connection for further use
        if( clientSocket[current] != INVALID_SOCKET){
        //set new client to non blocking
            check = ioctlsocket(clientSocket[current], FIONBIO, &NonBlock);
            if( check == SOCKET_ERROR){
                printf("Error setting client to nonblocking mode. %d.\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(clientSocket[current]);
                continue;
            }
            else{
                printf("Accepted client connection request \n");
            //recieve data
                check = recv(clientSocket[current], recvArray, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
                if( check == SOCKET_ERROR){  //close connection if error
                    printf("error recieving login data. %d \n", WSAGetLastError());
                    closesocket(clientSocket[current]);
                    continue;
                }
                if( check == 0){//no data is recieved then client disconnected
                    printf("ERROR no data, client dsiconnected.\n");
                    closesocket(clientSocket[current]);
                    continue;
                }
                else{

                    for(int n=0; n<check +1 ; n++){    //must be request message for data per NTRIP 1.0
                        clientRequest << recvArray[n]; //place read char bytes into stringstream object for parsing.
                    }
                    //if request is good returns a client requested source, username, and true false for data send.
                    checkClientRequest(clientSocket[current], client[current].source, client[current].connected, client[current].user);

                }
            }
        }
    }//end of check client listen socket
for(unsigned int i=0; Total>0 && i<TotalSockets; i++){
        LPSOCKET_INFORMATION SocketInfo = SocketList[i];
        //check if client sends GGA string
        if(FD_ISSET(SocketInfo->Socket, &Reader)){
            Total--;
            SocketInfo->DataBuf.buf = SocketInfo->Buffer;
            SocketInfo->DataBuf.len = BUFFERSIZE;
            Flags = 0;
            SocketInfo->RecvBytes = sizeof(SocketInfo->DataBuf);
            check = WSARecv(SocketInfo->Socket, &(SocketInfo->DataBuf), 1, &(SocketInfo->RecvBytes), &Flags, NULL, NULL);
            if( check == SOCKET_ERROR){
                FreeSocketInformation(i); //shuts down client socket if socket error
                continue;
            }
            else{
            memcpy(recvArray, SocketInfo->DataBuf.buf, SocketInfo->RecvBytes +1);
            //print data on screen change to sort lines
            printf("%s \n", SocketInfo->DataBuf.buf);
            }
        }
```

There's more to it than just this but how do I track the structure SocketInfo with my clientSocket[]'s?

Comment: Why not put a pointer to the `Client` structure in the `SOCKET_INFORMATION` structure?

Comment: Please don't use select on Windows. It's provided just for compatibility with Berkeley sockets and it's just *not* the Windows way. Use threads, Windows messages, IOCP, completion events, completion routines, ...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Just because it is not "the Windows way" does not mean `select()` can not or should not be used at all.  It works just fine when used properly, and there are plenty of situations where it is easier to use then writing code "the Windows way", which usually requires breaking code up into pieces which are harder to manage.

Comment: OK I just added a IndexNo value into the SOCKET_INFORMATION structure and and pass the current client array[number] to the socket structure when filling out the socket info. Hopefully it will work.